# Attempt to add 'foo' to a static workspace, when using input command?

Tags: matlab, input

I wrote a program that contains the **`input`** command in order to get the required info from user. but when I try to read the input, I encounter with this error:

```
Attempt to add "g" to a static workspace.
```

and my code is:

```
baseFunctionType = input('Please enter the type of base functions?(Polynomial = P ,Gaussian = G)');
```

I read some posts about the same error message, but with different context they were in! Is there any way to do that!(I don't want to use GUI)

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably need to use the following syntax given that your input is a string:

```
baseFunctionType = input('Please enter the type of base functions?(Polynomial = P ,Gaussian = G)','s');
```

Check the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/input.html) for more details.